# Ubuntu privileges for ownCloud

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, chown, privileges

- Who should be the owner of my `/var/www/html/owncloud` directory? By default it is `root` because I have to unzip as `root` in this directory.
- Should I change the owner of this directory to `www-data` then?
- Should I do it recursively?

I understand that the ownCloud data directory (which is located at `/home/<username>/owncloud-data`) has to have www-data as owner so the Apache server is able to write to that directory.

Same question applies to WordPress and MantisBT for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owncloud provides comprehensive settings for 'strict' permissions in its administration manual. Check here: [OC Manual](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_wizard.html#strong-perms-label)
Other settings might be possible. Please keep in mind that with strict settings, auto update does not work.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! :)